# MS Access Report Formatting - Grouping

Tags: forms, ms-access, report

I've been unsuccessful in determining how to make the "Category" column only display the value once per grouping, as it is grouped on its self.

Here is what I have:

[image]

I would like to make it so that "Beverage" and other following grouped categories only display once. It also needs to be in-line with the first description item.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok!,

I figured it out. In order to do so, you need to go to the text box's properties and in format set "Yes" to "Hide Duplicates".

here is an image:

[image]

Hide Duplicates is the 6th to last item on the format tab of the control properties window.

Cheers!